# i want to load email id in dropdownlist control with checkbox and send message on those email ids

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have one table **email** which contain email id of all employee.I want to dynamically load this **email id** in **dropdownlist with checkbox** added in that **dropdownlist**.

If there are **10 email** id then there should be **10** **checkbox** in front of **email id** in **dropdownlist control** in **asp.net with c#**.

If I check **4** **checkbox** in that **dropdownlist** then in **dropdownlist** it should display like **4 selected**.

My main aim is to send **message** on all those **email id** which are checked in **dropdownlist control**.

Can any one provide me both the code of how to load load **email id in dropdownlist with checkbox** in front of **email id** and also send **message on multiple email id** which are **check in checkbox**.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the example that might help you. You need to write customized code for displaying 4 selected.

http://www.dotnetgallery.com/kb/resource55-Checkbox-list-in-Dropdown-using-Aspnet-Ajax-PopupControlExtender-control.aspx

Comment: can u give me code for how to send message to multiple email id.i would be very thank full to you